# Ceiling Fan and Light stop working

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a Ceiling Fan and Light stop working yesterday. I used a [klein](http://www.kleintools.com/catalog/electrical-testers/non-contact-voltage-tester) to test the voltage, the switch is OK, and when the I turn on, I can detect the voltage around the bulb. What could be the issue?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of tester will tell if the wire is hot. A bad return path (white wire) could be the cause. Also the lamp can be bad, but you said both quit so I would check to see if the neutral wiggled loose.

Comment: Can you let me know how to check the neutral wiggled loose? Thanks.

Comment: With both the fan and light not working The box on the ceiling where you circled Red would be a good place to look first. With power off drop the cover and find your neutral wires give them a tug and make sure there are none just floating/ broken off. if not there double check the switch neutrals. My bet would be above the fan as they usually wobble a bit and wires can wiggle loose or break off.